# React Context why I'm running into error `useData No DataProvider available`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello I'm creating a library which handles the basic auth fetching for the users.

Currently I run into issue in tests that points me to useAuth hook with `useData No DataProvider available` error.

DataProvider is a simple store

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { dataStateReducer } from 'src/store/dataStateReducer';
import { DataDispatchContext, DataStateContext } from 'src/context/data/dataContext';
import { initialState } from 'src/store/dataState';

import type { DataProviderProps } from './DataProvider.types';

export const DataProvider = ({ children }: DataProviderProps) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(dataStateReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <DataStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <DataDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>{children}</DataDispatchContext.Provider>
    </DataStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And hooks for this provider

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { DataStateContext } from 'src/context/data/dataContext';

export const useData = () => {
  const state = React.useContext(DataStateContext);

  if (!state) {
    throw Error('useData No DataProvider available');
  }

  return state;
};
```

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { DataDispatchContext } from '../context/data/dataContext';

export const useDispatch = () => {
  const dispatch = React.useContext(DataDispatchContext);

  if (!dispatch) {
    throw Error('useDispatch No DataProvider available');
  }

  return dispatch;
};
```

And the `useAuth` which explodes with mentioned error in the one test case

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { useData } from 'src/hooks/useData';

export const useAuth = () => {
  const { isLoadingAuth, user, company } = useData();

  const isAuthorized = !!user;

  return {
    isLoadingAuth,
    isAuthorized,
    user,
    company,
    companyName: company?.name,
  };
};
```

And the test that is failing, note that DataProvider is included in the `OAuthProvider`

```
export const OAuthProvider = ({ token, authSpaUrl, apiUrl, children }: OAuthProviderProps) => {
  return (
    <ClientProvider url={apiUrl}>
      <DataProvider>
        <AuthProvider ottToken={ottToken} authSpaUrl={authSpaUrl}>
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </DataProvider>
    </ClientProvider>
  );
};
```

```
const OAuthProviderConsumer = () => {
  const { isLoadingAuth, isAuthorized } = useAuth();

  if (isLoadingAuth) {
    return <p>Loading auth...</p>;
  }

  if (isAuthorized) {
    return <div>Authorized</div>;
  }

  return <div>Not Authorized</div>;
};

const createWrapper = (token?: string) => {
  render(
    <OAuthProvider authSpaUrl={FAKE_SPA_AUTH_URL} apiUrl={FAKE_AUTH_DOMAIN} ottToken={token}>
      <OAuthProviderConsumer />
    </OAuthProvider>,
  );
};

describe('OAuthProvider - responsible for adding useAuth hook for user', () => {
  it('should validate the provided token and authorize the user if the token is valid', async () => {
    createWrapper(VALID_TOKEN);

    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText('Loading auth...'));

    expect(screen.getByText('Authorized')).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: I don't see `DataProvider` in your test, where should it grab `dispatch` then?

Comment: He is using two different context, `DataStateContext` and `DataDispatchContext`, it is not necessary, but isn't a problem.

Comment: sorry, the `DataProvider` is there it is just a part of OAuthProvider I will update the description